# How to read frames from a video MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, video

I have to read video frames one by one from image and store each frame in an array which I can further use. I guess there must be some loop which can do this work.

I am using:

```
video=VideoReader('sample.avi')
frm = read(video) % to get frame
```

but MATLAB gives error on read command and close automatically as shown in the attached image:

[image: error image].

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: MATLAB has encountered an internal problem and needs to close on executing read command :( i am using 2012b

Comment: Please put the error message and the "Details" in your question.

Comment: i add image in question please see

Comment: That sounds like an internal bug.  Suggest you contact MathWorks.  MATLAB should not be crashing when reading in frames from a video.

Comment: try a different .avi file, just in case

Comment: yes changing .avi file, works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[From the documentation:](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/videoreader.html)

```
v = VideoReader('xylophone.mp4');

while hasFrame(v)
    video = readFrame(v);
end
```

or from the [documentation of VideoReader.read](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/videoreader.read.html)

```
video = read(v,[1 Inf]);
```

Comment: in above code, error in hasFrame line Undefined function 'hasFrame' for input arguments of type 'VideoReader'. and when executing read(v,[1 inf]) also gives error (MATLAB has encountered an internal problem and needs to close on executing read command) :( i am using MATLAB 2012b.

Comment: @usman what about the seconds one?

Comment: 2nd one gives Undefined function 'hasFrame' for input arguments of type 'VideoReader'. I am using matlab 2012b. dont know what error it is about?

Comment: @usman Unfortunatedly I can not acces documentation from 2012, so I cant help you more. What about reading the documentation bysyourself?

Comment: @AnderBiguri: The code from the question is okay, read called without parameters is allowed.

Comment: yup ander your code is write, but dont know why this error comes because i searched on google everyone uses these commands and when i am going to use it sucks. can you help with it?

Comment: after execution of video = read(v,[1 Inf]); how can i extract images one by one from variable video?

Comment: but boss this command only extract the last frame. i want to extract each and every frame. is it possible?

Comment: @usman no it doenst. give `ii=1` it will get the first, 2 the second and so on.. Please, do not ask questions this simple withou ttriying.

Comment: thankyou ander. sorry to disturb you by my simple questions, i am new to MATLAB therefore i have no idea how to deal with this simplicity..by the way again thankyou for alot of help. you solved my problem :)

Comment: @usman no problem, i am glad i helped. consider accepting te answer as valid ;)